# Why does inserting intermediate non standard elements in the DOM break flex boxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flexbox

I witnessed this with Angular JS directive-elements, but here is a minimal reproduction code:

**OK code** (the parent div width is 30rem) :

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}
.parent {
  flex: 0 0 30rem;
  background-color: BlueViolet;
}
.child {
  flex: 0 0 15rem;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}
.text {
  background-color: DarkOrange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <span class="text">Dummy text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**KO code** (the parent div width is NOT 30rem : it has the size of the text under Chrome & Firefox, and is 15rem under IE11):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}
.parent {
  flex: 0 0 30rem;
  background-color: BlueViolet;
}
.child {
  flex: 0 0 15rem;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}
.text {
  background-color: DarkOrange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <dummy-tag>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        <span class="text">Dummy text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dummy-tag>
</div>
```

Is this a new [flex bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) ?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how flex works.  It's not about non-standard elements (By default treated as `display:inline` elements), it's about any element that doesn't have the right `display` value.

Put a `<div>` there instead of a `<dummy-tag>` and you'll have a similar effect.